# Logstash regex to match all messages that dont have a certain number of delimiters

Tags: regex, logstash

This seems like a pretty simple problem but at this point i think i just need a second pair of eyes.  I have filebeat log messages coming into a logstash pipeline.  These messages will have multiple lines when you include the stacktraces of the exceptions.  Below are a few examples.

`code`

```
BL: | LL: ERROR | TS: random value | MSG: Payment Type  2 |  :EL


BL: | LL: ERROR | TS: 2020-05-03 09:06:29,932 | AR: 38.0.0.51 | LOC: 00742 | USER: 
DASHBOARD_REFRESH | HOST: 0.0.0.0 | DC:  null | MSGID: 1231456478912314869156: |SC: 
some.java.class | MSG: SOME useful ERROR Message  |  
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Fictitious NullPointerException
at StackTraceExample.method111(StackTraceExample.java:15)
at StackTraceExample.method11(StackTraceExample.java:11)
at StackTraceExample.method1(StackTraceExample.java:7)
at StackTraceExample.main(StackTraceExample.java:3)
:EL
```

`code`

I want to match on the first message by identifying that it doesn't have exactly 11 pipes to add the tag "Delimiter Error" and allow the second message to continue through my pipeline. The expression as it stands actually makes the logstash process crash.

`code`

```
filter {
if [message] =~ /^(\|{0,10}|\|{12,})$/{
    mutate {
            add_tag => [ "Delimiter Error" ] 
        }   
    }
}
```

`code`

Comment: There should be a pipe present, but not 11 pipes? `^(?!(?:[^|\r\n]*\|){11}[^|\r\n]*$)(?=[^|\r\n]*\|).+$` https://regex101.com/r/HsZBia/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current pattern `^(\|{0,10}|\|{12,})$` matches either 0-10 or more than 12 pipes in a row and will not match any other character.

If you want to match a string which contains a pipe, but not 11 pipes:

```
^(?!(?:[^|\r\n]*\|){11}[^|\r\n]*$)[^\r\n|]*\|.*$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!` Negative lookahead

  - `(?:[^|\r\n]*\|){11}[^|\r\n]*$` Match 11 pipes and assert end of string
- `)` Close lookahead
- `[^\r\n|]*` Match any char except a newline or pipe
- `\|.*` Match a pipe and match 0+ times a newline
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SUvgGx/1)